# Php: How to use $_POST under where clause

Tags: php, mysql, post, where-clause

I im having an issue with this, Im not able to retrieve data from db.

This Works fine

```
$user_date = ISSET($_POST['input_date']);

$query1=mysql_query("SELECT START_TIME,END_TIME FROM dummy where MDATE='2012-03-18'")
```

but this doesn't. only change is I've used $user_date

```
$user_date = ISSET($_POST['input_date']);

$query1=mysql_query("SELECT START_TIME,END_TIME FROM dummy where MDATE='$user_date'")
```

Comment: Care to read what `isset()` function does? It is always a good idea to read functions' description in the manual before using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/function.isset.php) returns a boolean value if the variable has been set, not the value of the variable itself. You need something like:

```
$user_date = isset($_POST['input_date']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['input_date']) : '';
```

The above is a ternary operation. If the input value has been set, it is escaped and stored into `$user_date`.  Otherwise, an empty string is returned. You would need to decide what action to take when it isn't set, the part after `:`.  For example, you could return a default date instead:

```
$user_date = isset($_POST['input_date']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['input_date']) : '2012-03-18';
```

Comment: +1. Fast typing skills there. :) Fix the typos and all is well.

Answer (score -2):

That's normal,

```
$user_date = ISSET($_POST['input_date']);
```

isset retun a Boolean,

use the following

```
if (ISSET($_POST['input_date']))
$user_date = $_POST['input_date'];
$query1=mysql_query("SELECT START_TIME,END_TIME FROM dummy where MDATE='$user_date'")
```

On top of that you should use mysql_reapl_escape_string function or similar to avoid sql injection.

Hope it helps !

Comment: why not to add mysql_reapl_escape_string function or similar right to the code instead of just mention it?

Comment: because I don't type 12 words per sec ... -> 3 mins ago for the post bellow